# Django - AttributeError - 'User' object has no attribute 'validate'

Tags: django, oauth, twitter, authentication

I'm getting an AttributeError using rcrowley's django-twitterauth: http://github.com/rcrowley/django-twitterauth

Looks like it occurs when the validate() method is called on the user object, which the user object does not have. I don't know why the author did this. I'm really new to Django, wondering if anyone else knows. I know you can validate the model/data using the form object, but it looks like there's no form here:

```
@needs_user('auth_login')
def info(req):
 if 'POST' == req.method:
  req.user.email = req.POST['email']
  errors = req.user.validate()
  if not errors: req.user.save()
  return render_to_response('info.html', {
   'user': req.user,
   'errors': errors
  })
 return render_to_response('info.html', {'user': req.user})
```

Answer (score 2):

The default django `contrib.auth.models.User` may not have a `validate()` command, but the `twitterauth.models.User` *does* have one ... did you make any changes to ensure your project is using the twitterauth's model and not the default one ?